# How to calculate relative position of anchor?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I fear I misunderstood some fundamental stuff about the tikz way to calculate relative positions for anchors when defining shapes. In the following code I expect 2 lines to be drawn from (4, 2.8) -- (5, 0) and from (4, 3.2) -- (5, 5), but both lines start at the center node of the declared shape. I tried to use saved anchors and anchors directly - both have no effect. Why?

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}% 'crop' is the default for v1.0, before it was 'preview'
%\documentclass[crop,tikz,convert={density=300,size=800x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newlength{\originx}
\newlength{\originy}

\pgfdeclareshape{electric engine with connectors}
{
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}

    \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
    \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}

    \savedanchor{\connectorone}{
      \pgfextractx{\originx}{\pgfpointorigin}
      \pgfextracty{\originy}{\pgfpointorigin}  
      \pgfpoint{\originx+1.0}{\originy+0.2}
    }
    \anchor{connectorone}{\connectorone}

    \anchor{connectortwo}{
      \pgfextractx{\originx}{\pgfpointorigin}
      \pgfextracty{\originy}{\pgfpointorigin}  
      \pgfpoint{\originx+1.0}{\originy-0.2}
    }

    \backgroundpath{%
      \draw (0, 0) node[elmech](motor){M};
      \draw (motor.north) -- ++(0, 0.3) -- ++(0.7, 0) |- (1.0, 0.2);
      \draw (motor.south) -- ++(0, -0.3) -- ++(0.7, 0) |- (1.0, -0.2);
    }
}


\begin{document}
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid +(5,5);

    \node [shape=electric engine with connectors] (e1) at (3, 3) {};
    \draw (e1.connectorone) -- (5, 5);
    \draw (e1.connectortwo) -- (5, 0);
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: The wrong output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that context, if no unit is specified, `pt` is used. Hence, when you
do `\pgfpoint{\originx+1.0}{\originy-0.2}` you get the point that is 1pt right and 0.2pt above the origin. If you explicitly define the unit (as `cm`) the result is better.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}% 'crop' is the default for v1.0, before it was 'preview'
%\documentclass[crop,tikz,convert={density=300,size=800x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newlength{\originx}
\newlength{\originy}

\pgfdeclareshape{electric engine with connectors}
{
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}

    \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
    \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}

    \savedanchor{\connectorone}{
      \pgfextractx{\originx}{\pgfpointorigin}
      \pgfextracty{\originy}{\pgfpointorigin}  
      \pgfpoint{\originx+1.0cm}{\originy+0.2cm}
    }
    \anchor{connectorone}{\connectorone}

    \anchor{connectortwo}{
      \pgfextractx{\originx}{\pgfpointorigin}
      \pgfextracty{\originy}{\pgfpointorigin}  
      \pgfpoint{\originx+1.0cm}{\originy-0.2cm}
    }

    \backgroundpath{%
      \draw (0, 0) node[elmech](motor){M};
      \draw (motor.north) -- ++(0, 0.3) -- ++(0.7, 0) |- (1.0, 0.2);
      \draw (motor.south) -- ++(0, -0.3) -- ++(0.7, 0) |- (1.0, -0.2);
    }
}


\begin{document}
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw [help lines,opacity=0.2] (0,0) grid +(5,5);

    \node [shape=electric engine with connectors] (e1) at (3, 3) {};
    \draw (e1.connectorone) -- (5, 5);
    \draw (e1.connectortwo) -- (5, 0);
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, that explains it. For a scalable setting this leads to 

    \newlength{\posx}
    \newlength{\posy}

    \anchor{connectorone}{
      \pgfextractx{\posx}{\pgfpointorigin+\pgfpointxy{1}{0.2}}
      \pgfextracty{\posy}{\pgfpointorigin+\pgfpointxy{1}{0.2}}  
      \pgfpoint{\posx}{\posy}
    }

    \anchor{connectortwo}{
      \pgfextractx{\posx}{\pgfpointorigin+\pgfpointxy{1}{-0.2}}
      \pgfextracty{\posy}{\pgfpointorigin+\pgfpointxy{1}{-0.2}}  
      \pgfpoint{\posx}{\posy}
    }
 
Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: @MarkusW. I don't know.